# Sql Server Query DropDownList Selected Value

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

I have a DropDownList that pulls values from a table in sql server. I want the dropdownlist to populate the list of values based on a selection by the user but also display the contents of the rest of my table in case they need to change something. For ex:

ddl1 has values of: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 user selects 5, so the value displayed in ddl2 is five, but if you exand the ddl2 you will also see the values of one, two, three, four...

This is the code in my load event...

```
 If Not IsPostBack Then
      result = dal.dbConnect(DAL.dbType.SqlServer, ConfigurationManager.AppSetting("SQLServerConnection"))
        If result = "Successful" Then
          Try
            dt = dal.ExecuteSelectStoredProc(DAL.dbType.SqlServer, "StoredProc1", "@obj1", DropDownList1.Text)
            DropDownList2.DataSource = dt
            DropDownList2.DataTextField = dt.Columns.Item(1).ToString
            DropDownList2.DataBind()
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
         End If
    End If
```

Stored Procedure...

```
 USE [DB1]
    GO
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProc1]
    @obj1 nvarchar(4)
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT [Obj1], [obj2]
    FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Code]
    WHERE [obj1] = @obj1
    END
```

Comment: If you could post code please

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the AppendDataBoundItems property to true to preserve the existing values in the DDL:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems.aspx

If you're looking to implement a cascading effect with the DDLs, take a look at this:

http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2007/07/21/Code-Snippet-Cascading-DropDownLists.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In your `SelectedIndex` Change event method, write the following:

```
ddl2.SelectedValue = ddl1.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help, unfortunately none of them worked, so I ended up changing the way I set things up. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear why you want to have two drop-down lists, or what is in each.

If you simply want a dropdown list with all the values from a table, but with the value showing being a value previously selected, just say "ddl.SetSelectedValue(somevalue)".